# Type mismatch with Firestore Observer

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx

I am working on an app using googles firestore database system along with Angular and NgRx and NgRx Entity and Data.

I want to make a call to the database and return the data as an observable array of a given type (design). The problem is that observable returned by firestore is not the type I need, so the function will not work. Should I loop through the data and set each item? Is there somewhere I am missing to force the type? Is the call not working and therefore returning an error?

Here is the call to the firebase service.

```
    return this.afs.collection('designs', ref => ref
        .where('status', '==', 1 )
        .where('deleted', '==', false))
        .valueChanges();
```

Error message in npm start

```
Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<makDesign[]>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by forcing the type of the observable. I wonder if there isn't something more subtle.

```
    return <Observable<design[]>> this.afs.collection('designs', ref => ref
        .where('status', '==', 1 )
        .where('deleted', '==', false))
        .valueChanges()
```